# Extra validations on url before an object is created/saved to prevent SQL injection?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation

Hopefully this isn't an invalid question, but could someone please explain to me what happens when rails creates and saves an object to the database or updates one? I've put several validations in place, but I'm not sure if I've missed something as there doesn't seem to be too much information on how rails secures its models under the hood.

In this code the user is supplying some data(supposed to be a url), I check with a REGEX to see if it is a url. I'm wondering if I need to do any additional SQL protection techniques for something as complicated as a url?

```
    class ListLink < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :list
    default_scope -> {order('created_at DESC')}

    #the REGEX urls are matched against
    VALID_URL_REGEX = /\A(http:\/\/|https:\/\/|www|)[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(([0-9]{1,5})?\/.*)?\z/i

    validates :link_url, presence: true,
    format:{with: VALID_URL_REGEX, message: "Please enter a valid url."}
    validates :list_id, presence: true

    #if is a valid url, ping embedly for more information on it
    before_save :embedly #:set_link_info

    #not sure what checks rails does on attributes created after validation
    #any suggestions on how I can make these safer would be appreciated!
    before_create :title, presence: true, length:{minimum: 4, maximum: 200}
    before_create :image_url, presence: true


  private
    def embedly
        embedly_api = Embedly::API.new :key => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                :user_agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; mytestapp/1.0; my@email.com)'
        url = link_url.dup
        obj = embedly_api.extract :url => url
        #extract and save a title and image element to the database
        #are these validated by Rails too?
        self.title = obj[0].title
        self.image_url = obj[0]["images"][0]["url"]
    end
end
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you referring to SQL injection attacks specifically or also CSRF/XSS attacks?

Comment: Specifically SQL injection here, but any advice for the others would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No extra care required; `validates` is enough.
Using ActiveRecord you can be sure the input data is properly escaped.

```
User.last.update_attributes(first_name: 'DROP TABLE users;')
# => true    
User.last.first_name
# => "DROP TABLE users;"
```

You seems to misunderstand the purpose of `before_create`. It is a callback that's executed right before the record is added into the database. Its purpose is not to validate the object, but to execute custom code, as in the case with `:embedly`. You want to change `before_create` to `validates` here. The latter is called every time before the object is saved on both create and update actions. If you have

```
validates :title, presence: true, length:{minimum: 4, maximum: 200}
```

and your object has a too short title, `ActiveRecord` won't allow you to save it.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the information about validates! I did misunderstand before_create.

Answer (score 0):

As addition to @shock_one answer:

ActiveRecord will call [ActiveRecord::Base.connection.connection.quoute](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4a720a2cdefc1926e0bfa23b8febd71869093c59/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb#L8) on every property, which will properly escape the values against SQL Injections. Same happens if you use hash queries or question mark placeholders in you queries.

e.g

```
User.where(name: params[:name])  
User.where("name=?", params[:name]).
```

However if you write your own concatenated sql queries you have to use `qoute` on user input

```
c = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
User.where("name=#{c.quote params[:name]}")
```

Comment: Ah I see, may I clarify: by property you mean an object property? So ActiveRecord::Base.connection.connection.quoute will be called on any object properties/table columns + any virtual attributes?